# iTextSharp new memory stream or juggle file paths?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, itext

im still really new to programming, and ive boxed myself into a corner looks like with this WPF app i made. Ive created a process that is trying to overwrite the file that is being read in, so im getting an access violation. My question though is this...if my requirements for this app is to simply stamp a pdf with zero interest in the files name in the end, how can I read in the file and change it at the same time, i cant have a process that duplicates the pdf, it must overwrite the existing pdf and not create a duplicate file albeit with a different file name. Im hoping that reading the file into a memorystream is the answer, but im having a difficult time finding documentation that isnt in java, which i lack the ability to port over to c# from their examples.

[this is the error in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Gn3.png)

Here is the code doing the work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
                {

                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePaths[i]);

                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(filePaths[i], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
                    BaseFont font = BaseFont.CreateFont(); // Helvetica, WinAnsiEncoding
                    for (int j = 0; j < reader.NumberOfPages; ++j)
                    {
                        PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.GetOverContent(j + 1);
                        overContent.SaveState();
                        overContent.BeginText();
                        overContent.SetFontAndSize(font, 10.0f);
                        overContent.SetTextMatrix(10, 5);
                        overContent.ShowText(clientName
                                            + " #" + clientID
                                            + " DOB:" + dobDate
                                            + " " + admitType
                                            + " @" + admitDate);
                        overContent.EndText();
                        overContent.RestoreState();
                    }
                    stamper.Close();
                }

                //reset form
                inputBox.Text = "";

                clientNameText.Text = "";
                clientIDText.Text = "";
                dobDateText.Text = "";
                admitTypeText.Text = "";
                admitDateText.Text = "";
                errorLabel.Text = "";

                doneImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the constructor for `PdfReader` that takes a file path which is the most common but, as you've seen, it means you cannot write to the file since you are still reading from it.

Luckily there is an overload that takes a [raw byte array](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfReader.cs#l214) so you can just read the file on your own using [`System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass that into `PdfReader`

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePaths[i]));
```

Comment: So instead of reading in by file path and locking the file, this readAllBytes only pulls in the data, and then just references it maybe?

Comment: `ReadAllBytes()` reads the contents of the file into a byte array and that byte array then gets passed around. For very large PDFs or for machines with low amount of memory or high performance web sites being access by hundreds of people simultaneously this might be a problem but for day-to-day common usage it isn't an issue.

Comment: Man I tried building a byte array from a byte List, but never got it working, because i couldnt figure out the memory stream syntax, but had you not shown me that overload method, i would have never known i didnt have to reinvent the wheel. It works perfectly... Now i can pull in multiple pdfs to my filePaths array, and stamp more than one pdf at a time. thanks a million.